# How to display a particular cluster in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that includes test scores by year for each state, and I have clustered it using the following code:

```
cluster.m4 <- na.omit(states.data, cols="AVG_MATH_4_SCORE")
d <- dist(cluster.m4$AVG_MATH_4_SCORE)
hp <- hclust(d)
plot(hp, hang = -1, labels=cluster.m4$STATE)
rect.hclust(hp, k=4, border="red")
```

The output that I get looks like this:

[Dendrogram of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8cNB.png)

The way it is right now, there is no easy way to read the labels.  Is there a way for me to display just one of the clusters, so that I will be able to read the labels?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cutree` from stats to break your dendrogram into multiple parts. You can either specify

k: an integer scalar or vector with the desired number of groups

or

h: numeric scalar or vector with heights where the tree should be cut.

Based on your image, I think that cutting at a height of 15 would work:

```
cutree(hp, h = 15)
```